# Reading and counting of consecutive points

Tags: r, data.table

I have problems reading coordinates from a 2D space from a data.table as the following and reading out different qualities from it:

```
DT <- data.table(
                                      A = c(rep("aa",2),rep("bb",2)),
                                      B = c(rep("H",2),rep("Na",2)),
                                      Low = c(0,3,1,1),
                                      High = c(8,10,9,8),
                                      Time =c("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"),
                                      Intensity = c("0,0,0,0,561464,0,0,0,0,0,0","0,0,0,6548,5464,5616,0,0,0,68716,0","5658,12,6548,6541,8,5646854,54565,56465,546,65,0","0,561464,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0")

                     )
```

The "Time" and "Intensity" columns are referring to x and y values of a 2D space. The "Low" and "High" columns are referring to to boundaries on the x-axis ("Time"). 
Now I would like to check different qualities of the y ("Intensity") dimension within (< >) those boarders:

1. The highest number of consecutive points > 0:  (row1: 1, row 2: 2,..)
2. The total number of points > 0: (row1: 1, row2: 3,..)
3. The highest number of consecutive points > baseline (the baseline value should be taken from the Intensity value of the Low or High boundary, which ever is lower (so for row3 it would be 12, for the others 0)): (row3: 4, for all other rows it is the same as in 1.)

So the output should be a table like that:

```
DT <- data.table(
                              A =c(rep("aa",2),rep("bb",2)),
                              B =c(rep("H",2),rep("Na",2)),
                              Low = c(0,3,1,1),
                              High = c(8,10,9,8),
                              Time = c("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"),
                              Intensity = c("0,0,0,0,561464,0,0,0,0,0,0","0,0,0,6548,5464,5616,0,0,0,68716,0","5658,12,6548,6541,8,5646854,54565,56465,546,65,0","0,561464,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"),
                              First = c(1,2,7,0),
                              Second= c(1,3,7,0),
                              Third = c(1,2,4,0)
                  )
```

Has anyone an idea how that task could be handled? I was trying with data.table until now but if someone knows a better package for such tasks I would also be happy.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Yasel

Comment: One suggestion - when you create a data.frame or data.table, use it directly instead of `as.data.frame(cbind` as `cbind` returns a matrix and matrix can have only a single class.  In this case, all the numeric columns gets converted to character because of some character columns

Comment: thank you, adapted it accordingly

Comment: The description and the expected output is not matching.  When you say `highest number of consecutive points > 0` why is it 1 for row 0.  Is it based on `V6` column or `V5`?

Comment: Please change all <- to =,otherwise you don't get the named columns you want.

Comment: I edited your dataset.  FOr a `data.table`, by default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, also the assignment `<-` should be `=` inside

Comment: There is only one timepoint that has an intensity value > 0 in row 1 (561464) which is also in between the set boundaries on the x axis (>0; <8) as it is at time point = 4.

Comment: If that is the case, why it is 7 for row 3.  By counting, it seems to be 9

Comment: in row three it is: "6548, 6541, 8, 5646854, 54565, 56465 and 546" which makes 7 because the time point of "12" is "1" which is the lower limit and the time point of "65" is "9" which is the higher limit. Only points which are in between the limits count but not the points of the limits themselfes

Comment: I got the first and second column output but the third condition is not very clear to me.

Comment: Something like `cbind(DT, do.call(rbind, Map(function(u, v, x, y) {u1 <- as.numeric(u); v1 <- as.numeric(v[u1 >x & u1 < y]); i2 <- sum(v1 > 0); i1 <- with(rle(v1 > 0), pmax(max(lengths[values]), 0)); bs <- min(x, y); v2 <- as.numeric(v[u1 > bs]) > 0; i3 <- with(rle(v2), max(lengths[values])); data.frame(First = i1, Second = i2, Third = i3)}, strsplit(DT$Time, ","), strsplit(DT$Intensity, ","), DT$Low, DT$High)))` but the third column condition is not clear to me

Comment: Thanks a lot! The difference between the third and the first column is that in the third the limit is not 0 but the limit is the lowest of the two intensity values from the boundaries. In case of row3 the boundaries are at the intensity values "12" and "65". The lower of the two "12". So the consecutive points are "6548, 6541" and "5646854, 54565, 56465, 546" as the intensity "8" is below "12". So the result is 4 as it is the highest number of consecutive points with "12" as threshold

Comment: In the third row, the values are `"5658"    "12"      "6548"    "6541"    "8"       "5646854" "54565"   "56465"   "546"     "65"      "0"`  If we take the consecutive number of points with 12 as threshold then wouldn't it be 5

Comment: "5658" "12" "6548" "6541" "8" **"5646854" "54565" "56465" "546"** "65" "0".        
"8" becomes the new boundary so it does not count. sorry if that caused confusion

Comment: @yasel I think I got it.  Posted a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method with `base R`.  We `split` the 'Intensity', 'Time' columns by `,` into a `list`, then loop through the corresponding elements of the `list` along with the elements of 'High', 'Low' column, extract the values in the 'Intensity' based on the index from 'Low' to 'High', check whether it is greater than 0 (and also based on the conditional checking of values in 'Low').  Use `rle` to find the `length` of consecutive elements that are greater than 0 (or the 'Low' index).  Create a `data.frame`, `rbind` the contents of `list` and `cbind` with the original dataset

```
newCols <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(u, v, x, y) {
     u1 <- as.numeric(u)
     v1 <- as.numeric(v)
     v2 <- as.numeric(v1[u1 >x & u1 < y])
     i1 <- with(rle(v2 > 0), pmax(max(lengths[values]), 0))
     i2 <- sum(v2 > 0)
     lb <- match(x, u1)
     ub <- match(y, u1)
     v3 <- as.numeric(v[(lb+1):(ub-1)])

     i3 = with(rle(v3 > min(as.numeric(v[c(lb, ub)]))), 
                      pmax(max(lengths[values]), 0))
      data.frame(First = i1, Second = i2, Third = i3)
      },
         strsplit(DT$Time, ","), strsplit(DT$Intensity, ","), DT$Low, DT$High))

cbind(DT, newCols)
#  A  B Low High                   Time                                        Intensity First Second Third
#1: aa  H   0    8 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                       0,0,0,0,561464,0,0,0,0,0,0     1      1     1
#2: aa  H   3   10 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10               0,0,0,6548,5464,5616,0,0,0,68716,0     2      3     2
#3: bb Na   1    9 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 5658,12,6548,6541,8,5646854,54565,56465,546,65,0     7      7     4
#4: bb Na   1    8 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                       0,561464,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0     0      0     0
```